# While showing Button Choices, At that time I need to Hide SendBox in Bot Framework Node JS?

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework

Hide TextBox Activity while showing Choice Card Activity

Problem is showing Both Button choices and Text Typing Box ,User typing something else , At that time , I want to hide text acitivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to hide the send box without hiding the suggested actions at the moment. I opened a [Design Change Request](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/2427) on Web Chat's GitHub repo because I think it's a good idea. You should leave a +1. Best of luck!